# Mysql file permissions

Tags: linux, mysql, file-permissions

I was working to update a server, and accidentally set the entire var directory's owner to root..
This only really affected the mysql server, and I was wondering if anyone can tell me which files were affected.  I believe the mysql server only had a group (named mysql).
Thanks for any help,
Max

Edit
The error message I'm getting

```
[ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 13)
[ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you tried starting the server and looking at the error messages?

Comment: thanks for the catch, the error I'm getting is with the permissions to /var/run/ directory.  I'm guessing that is the only directory really affected (as it also broke screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysql that should fix this.

Comment: Haha, thanks for putting me on the right track, it was actually the permission on the /var/run folder itself. (crosses fingers, hopes database can write)